# how to prevent the arrow of a Qscrollbar from calling twice the same function?

Tags: python, slider, signals, qscrollbar

I've made a pyqt window to display signal in a matplotlib figure with a `QScrollBar` to see different part of the signal. 
My issue is when I plot 100 signal, the arrow of the `QScrollBar` calls twice the function that is called on a `valueChanged` signal.

When I put only 10 signals (`self.Sigs_dict = np.random.rand(10,105*self.Fs)`) I pass only once in the `update_plot` function where I print time info:

```
first 1572956286.183867
set 0.0
```

But If I increase the number of signal to 100 (`self.Sigs_dict = np.random.rand(100,105*self.Fs)`) I pass twice in the `update_plot` function. I then get :

```
first 1572956174.959317
set 0.009981632232666016
first 1572956175.6289513
set 0.0
```

I don't understand why it is happening and how I can get ride of that issue.

Here is the minimal example of my issue:

```
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
import sys
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Qt5Agg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas
import numpy as np
import time

class Viewer(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Viewer, self).__init__()
        self.parent = parent
        #######################################
        self.centralWidget = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralWidget)
        self.mainVBOX_param_scene = QVBoxLayout()
        self.mascene = plot(self)

        self.paramPlotV = QVBoxLayout()
        self.horizontalSliders  = QScrollBar(Qt.Horizontal)
        self.horizontalSliders.valueChanged.connect(self.update_plot)
        self.horizontalSliders.setMinimum(0)
        self.horizontalSliders.setMaximum(1)
        self.horizontalSliders.setPageStep(1)

        self.paramPlotV.addWidget(self.horizontalSliders)

        self.mainVBOX_param_scene.addWidget(self.mascene)
        self.mainVBOX_param_scene.addLayout(self.paramPlotV)

        self.centralWidget.setLayout(self.mainVBOX_param_scene)

        self.Fs = 1024
        self.Sigs_dict = np.random.rand(100,105*self.Fs)
        self.t = np.arange(self.Sigs_dict.shape[1])/self.Fs
        self.update()

    def updateslider(self):
        self.horizontalSliders.setMinimum(0)
        self.horizontalSliders.setMaximum(np.ceil(self.t[-1]/int(10))-1)

    def update_plot(self):
        t = time.time()
        print('first',t)
        self.mascene.update_set_data()
        print('set',time.time() - t)

    def update(self):
        self.updateslider()
        self.mascene.modify_sigs()
        self.mascene.update()


class plot(QGraphicsView):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(plot, self).__init__(parent)
        self.parent = parent
        self.scene = QGraphicsScene(self)
        self.setScene(self.scene)
        self.figure = plt.figure(facecolor='white')#Figure()
        self.canvas = FigureCanvas(self.figure)
        self.widget = QWidget()
        self.widget.setLayout(QVBoxLayout())
        self.scroll = QScrollArea(self.widget)
        self.scroll.setWidget(self.canvas)

        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.scroll)
        self.setLayout(layout)

    def modify_sigs(self):
        self.Sigs_dict = self.parent.Sigs_dict
        self.t = self.parent.t
        self.Fs= self.parent.Fs

    def update_set_data(self):
        ts, te = self.get_ts_te()
        t = self.t[ts:te]
        for i,line in enumerate(self.Lines):
            line.set_data(t, (self.Sigs_dict[i, ts:te]) + i)
        self.axes.set_xlim((ts/ self.Fs, ts / self.Fs + 10 ))
        self.canvas.draw_idle()


    def update(self):
        self.figure.clear()
        plt.figure(self.figure.number)
        self.axes = plt.subplot(1, 1, 1)
        ts, te = self.get_ts_te()

        self.Lines = []
        for i in range(self.Sigs_dict.shape[0]):
            line, = plt.plot(self.t[ts:te], (self.Sigs_dict[i,ts:te]-np.mean(self.Sigs_dict[i,ts:te]))+i)
            self.Lines.append(line)

        self.canvas.setGeometry(0, 0, self.parent.width()-100, (self.parent.height()-100))
        self.canvas.draw_idle()

    def get_ts_te(self):
        win_num = self.parent.horizontalSliders.value()
        ts = int(10 * (win_num) * self.Fs)
        te = ts + int(10 * self.Fs)
        if te > len(self.t):
            diff = te - len(self.t)
            ts = ts - diff
            te = len(self.t)
        return ts, te

def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Viewer(app)
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to counter the issue.
I add `self.horizontalSliders.setEnabled(False)` before the matplotlib figure update and I set it to True when the update is finished. So I have:

```
def update_plot(self):
    self.horizontalSliders.setEnabled(False)
    t = time.time()
    print('first',t, self.horizontalSliders.value())
    self.mascene.update_set_data()
    print('set',time.time() - t)
    self.horizontalSliders.setEnabled(True)
```

I don't know if it is the right way to do it but it works

Answer (score 1):

I see this occur when you try to move the slider more than one increment.  As soon as the value changes 1 increment you get an update, and then another when when the value changes again.  Because the drawing time for 100 signals is noticeably slower than for 10, the GUI response is slower, thus the slider tends to give multiple updates instead of jumping to the final value.

The simple fix for this is to change your connected signal to

```
self.horizontalSliders.sliderReleased.connect(self.update_plot)
```

The `sliderReleased` signal will assure your done moving the slider before doing your update.

The downside to this approach is that single mouse click on the arrows aren't captured, only a drag of the bar.  If you want to handle both while preventing multiple updates, you'll need to create state variable to decide which mode you are in.  You can look at the `sliderPressed` signal to see if the user is dragging the slider.  If they are, look at the `sliderReleased` signal for completion.  If not, use the `valueChanged` signal.

BTW... QT's signals ans slots are great but this type of signal recursion is very common and you often need to put in extra checks to prevent multiple calls to expensive redraw functions, etc..

Comment: In fact it happens when I'm asking for just one increment. I mean I click only once on the arrow, so the increment should be one. My issue with sliderReleased signal is that I will not be able to use the mouse wheel anymore, right? for now I'm trying to block the signal during the redraw but it doesn't work.

Comment: On my machine I don't see multiple udpates when clicking on the arrows, with either 10 or 100 signals.  I only see this when trying to drag the slider.

Comment: could you try with more signals, like 2 or 3 hundred ?

Comment: Maybe it is Windows specific :(

Comment: When pressing the arrow, I don't see this with even 1000 signals.  Try printing the `horizontalSliders.value()` inside your `update_plot` to see if your actually jumping multiple values.

Comment: When I'm doing this, it display 1 and 2. So it really is two one step increments.